# How to finalize a debug session after a windows phone app has been closed?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Each time when a windows phone app has been closed the associated debug session under VS 2010 was closed too. That scenario has been working perfect until Windows 8 + WP SDK 8 was installed.

Now a debug session is not finalized under an emulator neither under a device.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature. The debugger remains attached to the app to allow you to easily debug background tasks. Just press the "stop" button to dettach the debugger.

More explanations here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/08/23/new-visual-studio-2012-debugging-features-for-the-windows-8-app-lifecycle-model.aspx

I'm currently unaware of any way to disable that feature.

Comment: I hate this feature each time when I need to close app and continue I need to press STOP and ansver to the stupid question "Do you want stop debugging?"